# Stateless or stateful C# actors

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stateless

I'm designing a project which will activate and control many asynchronous actors simultaneously.

I'd like to ask, which approach should I use for more stability and scalability?

Stateless or stateful?

As far I as I see the difference, it looks like:

a. Stateful

```
Actor _act = new Actor (long key);

_act.DoSomething (object _what);
```

b. Stateless

```
Actor _act = new Actor (long key);

_act = _act.DoSomething(object _what);
```

As I know, second way is expensive - memory reservation, etc. But this one, second approach allows to don't bother about state and locks.

What way is preferable for dotnet? The goal number of actors to reach is about 100k, with 2.5-3 mils operations per second for one node.

PS Each actor has its finite-state machine to compute.

For stateful its called by periodic async delegate

For stateless its called on every operation in consideration of time dimension.

Comment: I vote to close it, as it would match better on another stackexchange site and leads to discussion ( and maybe personal preference ), though I thinks this is an interesting topic.

Comment: I agree with @Sascha, this is subjective. I personally like the second approach, but I favor functional approaches and being able to chain statements. `_act.DoX().DoAlsoY();`

Comment: I'm afraid I missed the goal of the community, Im experiencing some lack of practice, so I'd like to know opinions. 
So if it is too subjective, close it.

Comment: What framework are you using for your Actors? Or is it something that you wrote yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The Actor Programming model is based around the idea that each Actor should be a unique and separate computational entity with self contained "state". It's hard to tell based on the code snippet that you've provided what benefits you might actually receive are by using one technique over the other but in my opinion at least you're somewhat defeating the very idea of Actors by not encapsulating their state in such a way that you can leverage things such as lock free code.